# Java EE injection not working on Glassfish

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, java-ee-7

(Please be kind, these are my first steps in Java EE).
I'm working with Netbeans 8.1, deploying an EJB module on a local Glassfish Server.
I have a glassfish-resource.xml with the following resource defined:

```
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/myDataSource"
```

And I have a DAO class where I'm trying to inject that resource

```
@Named
public class SimpleDal {
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/myDataSource", lookup = "java:app/jdbc/myDataSource")
    private static DataSource ds ;
```

I have tried several ways to make this work but I always end up with NULL in the variable ds. I've been debugging and querying the Context, and I always end up with the name `java:app/jdbc/myDataSource` not found.
Maybe I'm not doing something right, this is my first steps on Java EE (I've always developed for PHP). Can somebody please direct me in order to avoid losing more time? Thanks

Note: I've add the `@Named` annotation to the SimpleDal class because I've read somewhere that in order to Injection to work, I have to be on a Bean.

Comment: In CDI rarely is something allowed on static fields unless it is specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some time I finally found out that injection doesn't work reliably on static fields (at least on my setup). Changed the field to an instance field and It worked . Posting this answer for anyone who is facing the same situation